# Installing 2 versions of app on one device

Tags: iphone

I've got two branches of an iPhone app going. I would like to load them both onto my provisioned iPad at the same time. The iPad sees them as the same app though and writes over whichever one is currently installed. Does anyone have good system for loading two versions concurrently. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bundle identifier is what is used to identify different applications, so if you were to temporarily change it for one of them, that build would show up as a different application than the other.  It would still have the same icon, name, etc., but the system would think it was a separate application.